Power Automate: Send email once at end of day of only most recent modification
I have a power automate flow that sends an email each time a particular date field is modified. The date field is modified multiple times per day, so I am getting multiple emails per day. Instead, I want the flow to send only one email at the end of the day with only the last modification made to that date.
I currently have:
"When an item or file is modified" -> "Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)" -> "Condition" -> "If yes", "Send an email (V2)"
If you can, please be detailed with your step-by-step instructions because I am a beginner.

You need to make a "scheduled cloud flow" that runs on a schedule instead of being triggered by a change:

Then just have the flow grab the item you want to know about and send the email.

To address the comment...
You can add a "Get items" from SharePoint action, and then order by "Modified" descending, and then select the "top" one.  This will give you the most recently modified item from that list.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the most recenty modified item where the modification was to a specific date field. Unfortunately, the method above will get just the most recently modified item, it doesn't guarantee that the modification was made to the date field. If someone went in and modified the Title field (or any other field), and that happened to be the last thing done in that list that day, that's the item that would be returned.
The only thing I can think of would be to add a new date field to record the times when your specific date field gets modified, and then get the most recent one of those.
So, let's say the date field you want to track is called MyDate.  You would add a new date field called MyDateModified.  Then, you keep your current flow that is triggered when an item changes, and use your same logic to check the changes, and then if the condition is true (your MyDate field was modified), instead of sending an email, set the MyDateModified field on the current item to the current date/time.
Now you are tracking only the modified times when that specific date field got modified.
Then, in your scheduled flow, you can sort by MyDateModified descending, pick the "top" one, and then you will be getting the most recently modified item where it was your specific date field that was modified.

Then you can send your email from there.

What's next after the recurrence box? I don't want to grab all the items in a column. The items I want to grab are only the date columns that are modified.

@user122970 updated my answer
